# .getPosition in ListAdapter

Tags: android, arraylist

I'm just lerning Android for few 2 Weeks, so maybe my question is stupid, but I got two Problems with my code ....

```
//[improt etc.]
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {...

arrayList = new  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

//[...]

try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(uebergabe);
        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Fux");

        int i;
        for (i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {

            HashMap<String, String> Hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject jO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String headline = jO.optString("headline");
            Hashmap.put("headline", headline);

            String content = jO.optString("content");
            Hashmap.put("content", content);

            arrayList.add(Hashmap);

        }


            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_fuxenfibel);
            ListAdapterFibel adapterFibel = new ListAdapterFibel(this, R.layout.layout_fibel, arrayList);
            list.setAdapter(adapterFibel);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id)
                {
                       Intent intent = new Intent(Fuxenfibel.this, Fuxenfibel_Inhalt.class);
                       intent.putExtra("content",arrayList.getPosition(i).get("content"));
                       startActivity(intent);
                }
            });


    } catch (JSONException e) {

//[...]
```

I can't use

```
intent.putExtra("content", arrayList.getPosition(i).get("content"));
```

to get get the Position, it causes 'cannot resolve method' error, because it is not a `PublicMethod` of `ArrayList`, it's Method of `ArrayAdapter`.

Is there a similar method of `ArrayList`, or another way to fix this without rethinking the entire code?

My second Problem is the variable i in the same codeline, it throws "Cannot resolve symbol 'i' error. Will some how declaring i outside the for-loop fix this error?

When I do like this

```
//[...]
final int i;
for (i=0;i<jasonArray.lenght;i++)
//[...]
intent.putExtra("content",arrayList./*MISSING METHOD not.getPosition*/.get("content"));
//[...]
```

the for-loop can't do i++ cause it's final, when I declare it not final it can't be accessed from within inner class...

How to get the variable working outside the loop?

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: use `((HashMap<String, String>)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).get("content")`

Answer (score 0):

To get a position of an ArrayList you should use the [get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) method.

And for the 'i' var as its used on AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() inner class you should declare it final as you pointed, to overcome the problem of using it on a for loop you should declare it final to get the value then use another var to the loop.

So it should be

```
final int i;
for (int a=i;a<jasonArray.lenght;a++)
{
}
```

That in case you need to start on the value of i, but your code doesnt look like that...

Hope this helps